# Validate function works on ValidationTextBox but not on FilteringSelect. Why?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having a rather strange behaviour and don't know if it's because something I'm not doing right.

I trying to customize a Dojo FilteringSelect in my application to show invalid messages at my will. Looking at the API, I found a way to do it. This way works fine for ValidationTextBox.

Code to switch validation state:

```
var originalValidator = textBox.validator;
textBox.validator = function() {return false;}
textBox.validate();  
textBox.validator = originalValidator;
```

Here's a fiddle so you can take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/HGBnq/

If I change the ValidationTextBox to a FilteringSelect, it should work the same. But for some reason, it doesn't!
Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nachoargentina/HGBnq/421/

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dijit/form/FilteringSelect` does indeed inherit from `dijit/form/ValidationTextBox`, but it overrides `isValid` ([source](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/FilteringSelect.js#L51-L54)). `isValid` is what calls the validator function in `ValidationTexBox`.

You could compose your own `FilteringSelect` that uses the same method that `ValidationTextBox` uses for `isValid`, or whatever you wanted or needed to use.

Comment: If you want the original ValidationTextBox behaviour, set the `isValid` property to `function() {return this.validator(this.textbox.value, this.get('constraints'));}`